# Integrate Image Uploader plugin in CKEdtior with laravel 5.3

Tags: ckeditor, laravel-5.3, image-upload

i have integrate 'Imageuploader' in CKEditor but when i am setting 'useruploadfolder' and 'useruploadpath', it is showing me an error

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://ibm.bplaced.com/imageuploader/register.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Laravel File Manager 
Here is the link
https://github.com/UniSharp/laravel-filemanager